# INSERT with two SELECT from the same table and field but diferent position

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called `department (id, data1, data2, id_leader_one, id_leader_two)` and another table called peoples with columns `(id, name, ...)`.

The fields `id_leader_one` and `id_leader_two` refers `a id` from peoples table (foreign key).

I need a make insert clause like this

```
INSERT INTO department 
(id, data1, data2, (SELECT id FROM peoples WHERE name='xxx')
, (SELECT id FROM peoples WHERE name='xxx')
```

but this don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parenthesis at the end. It should be.

> INSERT INTO department (id, data1, data2, (SELECT id FROM peoples
>   WHERE name='xxx'), (SELECT id FROM peoples WHERE name='xxx'));

The semicolon tell psql engine that it is the end of the query.
Also, make sure those id records exist, i.e they are inserted before the this query.

Answer (score 0):

Not wrong. There are two people with the same name. Solved.